# custom ui form on menu click?

Tags: adminhtml, adminform, menu, ui-form, magento2.4.0

I'm try to add a form on menu click and it doesn't works. Can anyone knows??

```
<menu>
<update id="FME_Extensions::fmeextensions"
  title="FME Extensions"
  module="Magento_Backend"
  sortOrder="70"
  resource="FME_Extensions::fmeextensions"/>
<add id="FME_Extensions::outofstock" title="Out Of Stock Notification" module="FME_OutOfStockNotification" sortOrder="70" parent="FME_Extensions::fmeextensions" resource="FME_Extensions::fmeextensions"/>
<add id="FME_OutOfStockNotification::outofstockreport" title="Out Of Stock Report" translate="title" module="FME_OutOfStockNotification" sortOrder="10" parent="Magento_Reports::report" resource="FME_OutOfStockNotification::outofstockreport"/>
<add id="FME_OutOfStockNotification::outofstock_notify" title="Out of Stock Notification Reports" translate="title" module="FME_OutOfStockNotification" sortOrder="10" parent="FME_OutOfStockNotification::outofstockreport" action="outofstocknotification/index/report" resource="FME_OutOfStockNotification::outofstock_notify"/>
<add id="FME_OutOfStockNotification::outofstock_alert" title="Stock Alerts" translate="title" module="FME_OutOfStockNotification" sortOrder="10" parent="FME_OutOfStockNotification::outofstockreport" action="outofstocknotification/stock/alert" resource="FME_OutOfStockNotification::outofstock_alert"/>
<add id="FME_OutOfStockNotification::outofstock" title="Out Of Stock Notify" module="FME_OutOfStockNotification" sortOrder="50" parent="FME_Extensions::outofstock" action="outofstocknotification/index" resource="FME_OutOfStockNotification::outofstock"/>
<add id="FME_OutOfStockNotification::system_config"
  title="Out of Stock Configuration"
  module="FME_OutOfStockNotification"
  sortOrder="99"
  parent="FME_Extensions::outofstock" action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/age_verification" resource="FME_OutOfStockNotification::system_config"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Please look into dev console and let us know if you see any errors

Comment: I wanna know it from scratch

Comment: It's not showing any errors